# How to save design document / view in CouchDB database from Scala program?

Tags: scala, couchdb

I have written a scala program for creating new database, and adding documents/views into it.

```
object CouchDBTest extends App {

  val dbSession = new Session("localhost", 5984)
  val db = dbSession.createDatabase("couchschooltest")

  val newC1 = new Document
  newC1.put("Type", "Class")
  newC1.put("ClassId", "C1")
  newC1.put("ClassName", "C-2A")
  newC1.put("ClassTeacher", "T1")
  newC1.accumulate("Students", "S1");
  newC1.accumulate("Students", "S2");
  newC1.accumulate("Students", "S3");
  db.saveDocument(newC1)


  val viewDocClass = new Document
  viewDocClass.addView("Class", "function(doc) {if(doc.Type == 'Class') { emit([doc.ClassId, doc.ClassName, doc.ClassTeacher, doc.Students], doc);}}")
  db.saveDocument(viewDocClass)
}
```

When I run this code, it creates the new database in CouchDB and adds the class document in this database. However, it doesn't add the views into the database. It gives the runtime error while adding the viewDocClass as

> Error adding document - null null

For this I used [couchdb4j API](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/)